# Using language check module for python - "can't find Java" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I'm planning to use the Language-check module for python 3 in my poem making code. I was just testing it with

```
import language_tool
lang_tool = language_tool.LanguageTool("en-US")
text = "A sentence with a error in the Hitchhiker’s Guide tot he Galaxy"
matches = lang_tool.check(text)
print(len(matches))
```

but it gave me this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/.site-packages/language_tool/__init__.py", line 548, in get_server_cmd
    cmd = cache["server_cmd"]
KeyError: 'server_cmd'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/.site-packages/language_tool/__init__.py", line 559, in get_jar_info
    java_path, jar_path = cache["jar_info"]
KeyError: 'jar_info'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    lang_tool = language_tool.LanguageTool("en-US")
  File "/home/runner/.site-packages/language_tool/__init__.py", line 188, in __init__
    self._start_server_on_free_port()
  File "/home/runner/.site-packages/language_tool/__init__.py", line 323, in _start_server_on_free_port
    cls._start_server()
  File "/home/runner/.site-packages/language_tool/__init__.py", line 335, in _start_server
    server_cmd = get_server_cmd(cls._port)
  File "/home/runner/.site-packages/language_tool/__init__.py", line 550, in get_server_cmd
    java_path, jar_path = get_jar_info()
  File "/home/runner/.site-packages/language_tool/__init__.py", line 563, in get_jar_info
    raise JavaError("can’t find Java")
language_tool.JavaError: can’t find Java
```

I've looked at some similar questions and I know I probably need to put something in 'Path' but I don't know what specifically to enter. Thanks for your help!

Also I'm on doing this on repl.it, not IDLE.

Comment: What is this `language_tool` module, and how did you install it? It looks like for some reason it needs to have a Java runtime installed to do its work; how did you install Java?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/spirit/language_tool I didn't install it on to my computer, I'm only importing it in repl.it which is a website for writing code. I think I just downloaded Java off the internet

Comment: On that page, under "Prerequisites", it says "LanguageTool requires Java 6 or later." Do you have Java 6 or later installed? If so, how did you install it?

Comment: Yes I do, I installed it from https://www.java.com/en/download/win10.jsp

Comment: Wait... did you install Java on *your machine* or on `repl.it`? If you're writing your code on a cloud machine, and you want to install this `language_tool` module on the cloud machine, then that's where you'll need Java installed. I don't know anything about how `repl.it` works, so I can't help you there.

Comment: Okay thanks. I guess repl.it doesn't have Java installed. Annoying because I can never get IDLE to work because I can never get pip to install modules right.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Note: I'm adding this as an actual answer because the question was resolved in the comments.</sup>

Your question says:

> Also I'm on doing this on repl.it, not IDLE.

That means that you need to install this module *and all its prerequisites* into your `repl.it` environment, not into your local machine.

On the BitBucket link you provided, under "Prerequisites", the page says:

> LanguageTool requires Java 6 or later.

So you will need to ensure Java is installed into your `repl.it` environment somehow. I don't know whether that is possible or not. Alternatively, you can simply install this package and all its prerequisites locally instead.